# Anchor hidden by overflow moves into view on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple scroller (similar to the tag scroller at the top to Google images), which uses jquery/javascript.

```
<div class="chip-scroller widget">
    <a class="chip-scroller_nav chip-scroller_nav--prev">
        <span class="md-icon">arrow_back_ios</span>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="chip-scroller_chip">anchor</a>
        </li>
        <!-- more items here -->
    </ul>
    <a class="chip-scroller_nav chip-scroller_nav--next">
        <span class="md-icon">arrow_back_ios</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The UL (list) has `overflow-x: hidden` set, so depending on the screen width and the number of items in the list, some items will be out of view, either to the left or the right of the visible area.

In the example below, 2 are hidden to the left, 3 are visible and 1 hidden to the right.

```
(hidden) (hidden) [visible visible visible] (hidden)
```

The list is positioned using javascript, and in the main navigated using the prev/next navigation buttons at each side.

The issue I have is that any of the items can be focused, whether they are visible or not, and focus means that they're immediately brought into view.

However, the scroller doesn't realise things have changed and it breaks my design. For instance the nav buttons may still show when there is nothing more to scroll in a particular direction.

The first thing I tried was to use **e.preventDefault()** to try and stop any default browser action, but it still bring the item into view. I'm using the on "focus" to capture the event:

```
$("body").on("focus", ".chip-scroller_chip", moveFocus);
```

This seemingly has no effect.

I could tag non-visible anchors with **tabindex=-1** but I don't want to stop the focus event happening, just regain control back from the browser.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What if you would add an if on move focus, assign another class with js to which elements you want to do actions, and with an if check if has a class .hassClass(), then if it does do something, else dont.

Add the class while you create an element. To the class that you dont want to show, add overflow: none, do the wanted thing to the other ones.

Atleast I would oreantate towards this.

Comment: I can capture the focus event and I'll probably be able to fix things by using the current  position of the focused object. However, I'm reacting to the browser rather than dictating what I want to do. Was hoping to stop the "movement" and  do my own thing.

Comment: With which function are you animating it?

Comment: I would use something like this jQuery: $c.animate({ scrollLeft: newStop }, duration);

Comment: Well to stop animation of jQuery element, you could use .stop(), .clearQueue(), .finish() hint, https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I don't want to stop the jquery animation, I want to stop the browser from repositioning the list before jquery clicks in, resulting on no animation.

Comment: So you want to prevent firing focus effect overall? via default? as in prevent from focusing which leads for the elemement to show up?

Comment: When an element is not in immediate view but is focused, the browser moves it into view before I can do anything about it. All I want to achieve is to stop the browser moving the element.

Comment: Yeh, I am not sure if you can stop browser from reacting how its supposed to react, how ever, you could play with displays and whats not, that would require more CSS than js though. But I still think that its doible, could you please give some graphic examples or roughly code of it. Its hard to imagine what you want to make, maybe there is some other ways to do it and currently our visions are probibally different.